# How to write scaleable code in Meteor

Tags: meteor

I've found some articles about Meteor and its scaling capabilities, but non of them fully explains how to do it. Most of them promotes Oplog Tailing, but that's not something I as a programmer needs to think about when I write my code, right?

When I look at [modulus.io's pricing modal](https://modulus.io/pricing), they offer me a varies number of servos my app will use, and claim that "Each Servo runs a single instance of your application." Running multiple instances is the way to scale a Meteor application, right?

But what problems come with this? Race conditions with the database can occur, right? How can I handle those? Do I need to design my application so race condition never occurs, or can I handle them when they occur?

Before thinking about scaling, I used to use `setInterval` to run background tasks (for example, to send me an email each hour with some data). However, I don't want each instance of my app to do that, but just one. What's the solution to this? Is it possible with Meteor?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To have a scalable Meteor app there are several things you need to seriously consider. Here are only the design considerations, less so on the proxying techniques or load balancing methods.

1) Avoid writing to or reading from the file system. Meteor's design decision of having an `Assets.getText`/`getBinary` only for files bundled in production, but no intuitive way to read or write files for this reason. If you have multiple dynamos you can get a request that can have data only on one server but not the other. Use S3 or GridFS to store any uploaded files off your drones.

2) If you have a `Meteor.setInterval` in your code, it will fire in concurrency with other 'drones', so make sure you instead code it out to work separately to the app itself via a cron job or making sure only a single drone of your app does this.

3) If you have `myCollection.find().observe..` anywhere in your code on the server side that isn't to do with a client instance, avoid it. This may create race conditions since all of them will get the information at the same time. Consider creating a separate app or making sure only a single drone can run these or they will run multiple times.

4) Avoid the use of variables that store user state. E.g you have a global variable like `UsersOnline = []` that you alter using a Meteor method or publish method. Consider storing the states on mongo or on redis so that each drone can access each other's states.

5) Make sure that each of the drones uses the oplog instead of the polling interval system. Otherwise there will be a delay in the other drone of your app when data is changed by another drone.

Be careful with queries that you use to ensure that oplog tailing is supported for them. Not all query types are supported, particularly where observers are involved. You can use the `facts` package to determine this.

6) Consider only using your drones for the websocket/ddp server connection. That is use `WebAppInternals.setBundledJsCssPrefix('https://xxx.cloudfront.net');` (if you use cloudfront, any other cdn works fine) as a CDN in front of your app. This ensures that your app loads fast but each drone isn't serving up static assets again and again. It also decreases each of their load

7) Be careful with any packages you add and make sure they also follow the above.

#### On the cron jobs/observers

You can either use a separate Meteor app, or make sure a single instance of your Meteor app does this. If you have access to an api that can determine which drones are online, you can make the one with the lowest port do the task. Be careful that you don't make one do a task on a constant port since that single drone may be offline, as a consideration of redundancy.

Comment: Nice answer! I'll add that [synced-cron](https://github.com/percolatestudio/meteor-synced-cron) can be used to replace `setInterval`. I wasn't aware of `setBundledJsCssPrefix`. Someone should write a blog post on exactly how to set that up.

Comment: What about callbacks to `Collection.deny`? Before I allow inserting a comment, I want to make sure the post the comment belongs to exists. Here can a race condition occur, since after I've checked the post exists and before the comment gets inserted into the database, the post may be deleted. I guess this is a general problem, and not limited to `Collection.deny`. [Database transaction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction) is the solution, right? Can one utilize that in Meteor?

Comment: @PeppeL-G TLDR: I dont know of a good way to the concurrency problem at the moment. You're right, its a bit tricky in this case the issue can be solved with document level locks or db transactions. Thing is, since these occur on the mongodb-level I think they can get through to the oplog (though i'm not sure) - theoretically an observer could see data even on a locked document if this was true. At the moment little can be done on this, you could use collection level locks but there is a performance cost, document level locks were just introduced in 2.8.